# Error when creating community page of custom object in Production & Sandbox

Tags: community

I have a custom object that I am trying to create a new community object page for.  I am getting the below error.  I have tried different browsers.  I have done this many times & have never had this problem.
[image]

Comment: This is a gack, an internal error. You'll likely need to work with Salesforce Support to resolve it.

Comment: Thanks - I just opened a case with Salesforce.

Comment: I am still waiting for Salesforce's help on this.  Any thoughts on what I can do to resolve it?